# Where to find JRE Emulation library supported by GWT 2.3.0?

Tags: java, gwt

How can I make out what all JRE classes are supported by JRE Emulation library in **GWT 2.3.0**?

I looked into:

> http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util

But, this seems to be supported by Latest version and not the older one which I am looking for...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Wayback Machine has 2.4, but not 2.3: http://web.archive.org/web/20121125090536/https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/RefJreEmulation

Easiest is to look at the changes, for example the changes between 2.3.0 and 2.6.0: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+log/2.3.0..2.6.0/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul

The reason GWT doesn't keep old documentation online is that we really want people to upgrade ASAP after a release. 2.3.0 is nearly **THREE YEARS OLD**, and we're talking about a **web** toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If you possess a genuine gwt-user-2.3.0.jar (and/or gwt-user-2.3.0-sources.jar) you can look it up yourself.

The JavaScript-based emulation of the JRE resides in the com.google.gwt.emul package.

Example:

JRE 1.8 has a java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(char) method. GWT emulation for java.lang.Character lives in com.google.gwt.emul.java.lang.Character, but there is no isWhitespace(char) method present, ergo: no emulation exists for this particular method.

(The above method should work for other GWT versions, of course.)